# remove a word from a string sed?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to strip the text and the space 'localhost ' and put what is left into a variable. I'm really unclear how to parse the string with `sed` and then parse the result into a variable - any help would be appreciated

Example:

input variable: `'localhost CPU'`

output variable: `'CPU'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a="localhost CPU"
b="${a#* }"
echo "$b"
```

Output:

```
CPU
```

Comment: Could just use one variable.

Comment: @User112638726: Yes, if you do not want to keep `$a`.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this:

[Using Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
a="localhost CPU"
b="${a/localhost /}"
echo "$b"
```

Using `cut`:

```
b="$(echo "$a" |cut -d" " -f2)"
```

Using `tr`:

```
b="$(echo "$a" |tr -d "localhost ")"
```

Using `grep` (with perl regex):

```
b="$(echo "$a" |grep -oP "(?<=localhost ).*")"
```

Comment: upvoted for the `grep -P`! For some reason, I never noticed that in the grep manual...

Answer (score 0):

```
strppedLocal=$(echo "$dataItems" | sed 's/[^ ]* //')
```

where `$dataItems` contains `'localhost CPU'`

Comment: I answered this myself with the above. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: or without pipe: `strppedLocal=$(sed 's/[^ ]* //' <<< "$dataItems")`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it the following way: Firstly I echo the contents of the variable and pipe this to sed, that then searches for "localhost " and replaces it with nothing. The output of everything is then stored in a variable called `output`.

```
a="localhost CPU"
output=`echo $a | sed -e "s/localhost //g`
```